# Set value of text within a tab in c#

Tags: c#, ironpython

I want to change the text value of a field if a condition is meet. I was able to succeed when just running on a main form, but I am unaware of how to scale up when using tabs. (I am new to GUI constructions and trying to learn the correct syntax). Here is the code as it stands in ironpython, but the problem should be the same as it is was in C#

```
class MainForm(Form):
  def __init__(self):
    #prepare tabs
    self.tabControl = TabControl()
    self.tabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    self.tabControl.Alignment = (TabAlignment.Top)
    self.Controls.Add(self.tabControl)
    self.addTabPage1('','')
  def addTabPage1(self, label, text):
    tabPage1 = TabPage()
    date_label = Label()
    date_label.Text = "Date"
    date_label.Location = Point(0, 0)
    date_textbox = TextBox()
    date_textbox.Location = Point(100,0)
    date_textbox.KeyUp += self.OnKeyUp
    tabPage1.Controls.Add(date_label)
    tabPage1.Controls.Add(date_textbox)
    self.tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage1)
  def OnKeyUp(self, sender, event): 
    if sender.Text=="TIME!":
        self.date_textbox.Text = "will get current time"
Application.EnableVisualStyles()
Application.Run(MainForm())
```

I assume the main problem is:

- date_textbox.KeyUp += self.OnKeyUp

and

- def OnKeyUp(self, sender, event):

  - if sender.Text=="TIME!":

    - self.date_textbox.Text = "will get current time"

How can i reference a tab when performing a function?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this question related to C# language?

Comment: So you want to convert C# into IronPython? Reconsider the question tag you used.

Comment: If you create a tab and its elements programmatically, it is helpful to store the reference somewhere, e.g., in a dictionary. So that you can access the element and its properties later from any function.